# Count for every unique value in a column - R

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe that contains a column representing the `'Year'` and another column that represents `'Type'`:

```
a  Year  Creams
1  2004   11
2  2004   12
3  2001   13
4  2004   14
5  2002   15
.  ....   ..
```

How do I count every year in column `'Year'` so it appears as:

```
a  Year  TypeCount
1  2004      3
2  2002      1
3  2001      1
```

It can be output into another dataframe, I don't mind. I just need it to be suitable to make a graph out of it at the end.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(Year) %>% summarise(TypeCount = n_distinct(Creams))` Or `df %>% count(Year)` if you just want to count number of rows for each `Year`.

Comment: what does %>% mean? It's not working in RStudio? Is this meant to be a substitute for something else?

Comment: Well, you need to load `dplyr` package for this, do it via `library(dplyr)`. There are other base R options in the links marked.